# Need help with a mysql query

Tags: mysql

I've developed a mysql query that tells me how many times each product was purchased over a specified timeframe.  I'm trying to figure out how to join this with my pageview tracking table so I can calculate the conversion rate for each product.  Here is the original query:

```
SELECT SUM( op.products_quantity ) AS num_sold, SUM( op.final_price * op.products_quantity ) AS total_sales, p.products_model, pd.products_name, p.products_id
    FROM orders_products AS op
    JOIN products AS p
    JOIN products_description AS pd
    JOIN orders as o
    WHERE p.products_id = op.products_id
    AND p.products_id = pd.products_id
    AND op.orders_id = o.orders_id
    AND o.date_purchased BETWEEN '2011-01-15' AND '2011-04-15"'
    GROUP BY p.products_id
    ORDER BY total_sales DESC
```

I have another query that gives me the page views per product:

```
SELECT pv.products_id, count( pv.timestamp )
FROM products_visits AS pv
WHERE pv.timestamp
BETWEEN '2011-01-15'
AND '2011-04-17'
GROUP BY products_id
```

The caveat is that the views data has just started being collected, so we want return results even if a given product_id is not in the views table, but is in the purchases table.

How do I combine those queries into a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` against a subquery.  I think this will do the job:

```
SELECT 
  SUM( op.products_quantity ) AS num_sold, 
  SUM( op.final_price * op.products_quantity ) AS total_sales, 
  p.products_model, pd.products_name, 
  p.products_id,
  visits.visits
FROM orders_products AS op
  JOIN products AS p
  JOIN products_description AS pd
  JOIN orders as o
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
     SELECT pv.products_id, count( pv.timestamp ) AS visits
     FROM products_visits AS pv
     WHERE pv.timestamp BETWEEN '2011-01-15' AND '2011-04-17'
     GROUP BY products_id
  ) visits ON p.products_id = visits.products_id
WHERE p.products_id = op.products_id
  AND p.products_id = pd.products_id
  AND op.orders_id = o.orders_id
  AND o.date_purchased BETWEEN '2011-01-15' AND '2011-04-15"'
GROUP BY p.products_id
ORDER BY total_sales DESC
```

Comment: That one got me there.  It wasn't working, but I put an ON clause after the left outer join:

ON visits.products_id=p.products_id

and that seems to have fixed it.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry about that.  I edited the answer so it's correct for future use.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `LEFT JOIN`: "first" you get all products and their sales data, and then you join the views data, if it exists.

try this:

```
SELECT p.products_id, 
count( pv.timestamp ) AS views,
p.products_model AS model,
SUM( op.products_quantity ) AS num_sold,
SUM( op.final_price * op.products_quantity ) AS total_sales,
pd.products_name
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN products_visits AS pv 
     ON pv.products_id = p.products_id
     AND pv.timestamp BETWEEN '2011-01-15' AND '2011-04-17'
JOIN orders_products AS op
     ON p.products_id = op.products_id
JOIN products_description AS pd
     ON p.products_id = pd.products_id
JOIN orders as o
     ON op.orders_id = o.orders_id
     AND o.date_purchased BETWEEN '2011-01-15' AND '2011-04-17'
GROUP BY p.products_id
ORDER BY total_sales DESC
```